# elastic search and logstash giving memory errors

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, logstash

I have elasticsearch 2.2.0 and logstash 2.1 installed in my system.

When i do a config test for logstash with:

```
sudo service logstash configtest
```

It gives following errors:

```
 There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 55545856 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2638), pid=7887, tid=140476386535168
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_71-b15) (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.71-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

What is the best way to get rid of this memory error, as there a are lot of prescribed solutions?

Also,

```
I have bootstrap.mlockall : true in elasticsearch.yml configured.
```

Can we configure elasticsearch bit differently?